# Differences of LinkedList .echo() vs .peek()

Tags: java-8, linked-list

In the oracle Java docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html:

`.element()` "Retrieves, but does not remove, the head (first element) of this list."

`.peek()` "Retrieves, but does not remove, the head (first element) of this list."

1. Is there a reason that you would want to use `.element()` as opposed to `.peek()`?
2. Is the answer to (1) is "No", why would a class need two methods with the same function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is described in the docs for Queue. Basically element throws an exception if there is an error (think empty list) whereas peek just returns a special value (probably null).   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Answer (score 4):

There are 4 methods.

1. Peek
2. Element
3. Poll
4. Remove

The behaviour of **peek** and **element** is almost same with a difference:

If a queue doesnt contain any elements the peek() method returns **null**.

The element() method behaves like peek(), so it again retrieves the value of the first element without removing it.

However, if the list is empty element() throws a `NoSuchElementException`.

Lastly, there are two other methods **poll** and **remove**.

The **poll()** method retrieves the value of the first element of the queue by removing it from the queue. If the list doesnt contain any elements, it will return null but doesnt throw any exception.

The **remove()** method behaves as the poll() method, so it removes the first element of the list and if the list is empty it will throw a NoSuchElementException.

Reference: 
http://www.davismol.net/2014/04/04/java-ocpjp7-difference-between-element-peek-poll-and-remove-methods-of-the-queue-interface/